# Configure ILogger using Serilog dynamically

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

Adding multi-tenant capability to an existing ASP.NET Core app that uses Serilog to log to files. Current configuration is:

Program.cs `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`:

```
builder.UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) => 
        logging.AddFile(context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
);
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    },
    "PathFormat": "Logs/Log_{Date}.txt",
    "FileSizeLimitBytes": null,
    "RetailedFileCountLimit": 14   
}
```

I would like to segregate Log files by tenant, so that they are written to `Logs/{TenantName}/Log_{Date}.txt`

I have a `Tenant` service registered that I can inject into a service to get the current Tenant. Is there a Serilog configuration class that I could implement and register that overrides the `PathFormat` for the current scope per-request?

Comment: look at Serilog.Sinks.Map; it may help a bit. The other thing is to take the configuration file syntax out of the picture - rig a testbed which does the config in code and make it work. Then fight the json after winning that battle